# Origem da palavra "putz"?

Tags: significado, português-brasileiro, origem-histórica

Um palavra da gíria brasileira que já oiço há décadas é *"putz"*.

Qual é a origem da palavra *putz* e quando se tornou comum o seu uso?

Deixo um artigo de referência em que a palavra *putz* surge integrada numa expressão que parece já ser idiomática [*"De onde vem a expressão «putz grila»?*](https://super.abril.com.br/coluna/oraculo/de-onde-vem-a-expressao-putz-grila/)

Comment: https://www.facetubes.com.br/noticia/244/voce-sabe-o-que-significa-a-expressao-qputz-grilaq Não sei porque o cara diz que a palavra é impublicável. Queria dizer: puta grila? No sentido de puta merda?

Comment: @Lambie é impublicável porque se um jornal começa a imprimir isso muitas vezes os leitores deixam de comprar, se um canal de TV começa a dizer essas expressões literais a audiência começa a mudar de canal. Para além do gosto da audiência também há regras para a comunicação social (hoje menos visíveis mas ainda existem) que proibem diversos usos.

Comment: Eu sei tudo isso. O que não sei é se a palavra era puta mesmo.

Comment: Para mim, *putz* sempre foi um jeito de falar *puta* sem falar *puta*, como *geez* ou *shoot* em inglês. Eu não comentei antes porque só me lembrei com o Lambie falando. Do *grila*, já não sei.

Comment: @Lambie nunca me tinha ocorrido que o sentido da palavra fosse esse (com mudança da última vogal para consoante) até tu e o Schilive associarem as palavras aqui nos comentários... Para mim é novidade embora já ouvisse o *"putz"* há muitos anos...

Comment: @bad_coder Como na própria pergunta você já cita um texto com a resposta, o que você procura é uma fonte melhor?

Comment: @stafusa eu não percebi o texto que linquei na pergunta quando o li a primeira vez. Mas a minha pergunta é também quando o uso de *putz* se tornou comum, isso o texto não explica claramente: se surge com o *putz grila* ou se o uso de *putz* já era comum antes sem o *grila*...?

Comment: @bad_coder Verdade, essa pergunta não está respondida lá.

Comment: Ainda se usa "oiço" em algum lugar desse planeta ?

Comment: Concordo com o @Schilive.  Seria uma forma suave de dizer PQP, embora muita gente nem perceba.  Já foi muito usada como interjeição (gíria) no século passado, e creio que atingiu o seu auge no período 1970-1980.  Hoje já não se usa tanto.